# Can't fix the arrowhead in a BezierCurve

Tags: graphics3d

```
t2 = Table[RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/2, {1, 0, 0}].{x, 0.2 + Sin[32 x]/15,0.6},{x,-0.47,0.07,1/200}];
t2r = Table[RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/2.5, {0, 0, 1}].t2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[t2]}];
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.0035], Orange, Arrowheads[.045],Arrow[BezierCurve[t2r]]},ImageSize-> 600]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `Arrowheads[{{.02, 1}}]` to set the size `.02` and the relatively position `1`.

```
t2 = Table[
  RotationMatrix[π/2, {1, 0, 0}].{x, 0.2 + Sin[32 x]/15, 
    0.6}, {x, -0.47, 0.07, 1/200}]; t2r = 
 Table[RotationMatrix[π/2.5, {0, 0, 1}].t2[[i]], {i, 1, 
   Length[t2]}]; Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.0035], Orange, 
  Arrowheads[{{.02, 1}}], Arrow[BezierCurve[t2r]]}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 ViewPoint -> {2.8, 1.1, 1.3}]
```

[image]